# What we call a compact and simply connected set ${\mathcal A} \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ with $\mu_n({\cal A}) > 0$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, lebesgue-measure

Let ${\mathcal A} \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ be closed and simply connected (also no inner "holes"). This set also has the following property: $\forall a \in {\mathcal A}$ and $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, ${\mathcal A} \bigcap \mu_n({\cal B}(a, \varepsilon)) > 0$, where ${\cal B}(a, \varepsilon)$ is an open ball, and $\mu_n(\cdot)$ returns the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

My question is: Is there any name for ${\mathcal A}$? Thanks!

PS: ${\mathcal A}$ can be $n$-dimensional ball, $n$-simplex, any convex set in ${\mathbb R}^n$ with $\mu_n({\cal A}) > 0$, etc. But ${\mathcal A}$ cannot be a Tootsie Pop (a $3$-dimensional ball with a $2$-dimensional line segement).

Comment: I've not heard of any name for this. What do you need a name for?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks a lot! (+1) I need this name to simplify the description in my paper (I could define one if it is not defined before in the literature). Actually, I am focusing on some invariant propery on ${\cal A}$ (under a series of transformations) when this set is endowed with some probability measure. I could just simply assume ${\cal A}$ is convex in ${\mathbb R}^n$ with $\mu_n({\cal A}) > 0$, but I still want to generalize it into non-convex sets with preserved measure.